# What is vnc4server configuration file for Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.04, configuration, vnc

I need **vnc4server configuration** file (*xstartup*) for **Ubuntu 13.04** for both **Gnome 3.8** and **Unity**, so it fixes the grey screen problem.

Answer (score 0):

gnome and unity don't work well with vnc server on Ubuntu. you can still load gnome via vnc but it does not work right. I highly recommend you to install xfce4 and use xfce4 session:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

and use this xstatup file

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```